# Sending mail (via java) works in eclipse but not on linux server

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, email, smtp

I am using below java code to send a mail.

```
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

And I'm able to send mail using this in eclipse (OS: Windows 7).
But after exporting the same code to a war file and hosting on a linux server,
I'm getting an error while sending the mail.

```
 ERROR [STDERR] javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
 ERROR [STDERR]   nested exception is:
 ERROR [STDERR]     java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1764)
 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1632)
 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1483)
 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:462)
 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:313)
 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)
 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
```

So why does it work in eclipse(windows) but not on linux?

I tried

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

in windows
[telnet smtp.gmail.com 587](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Moxg4.jpg)

Also tried the same in linux.

```
# telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying 74.125.200.108...
Connected to smtp.gmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP n8sm22997292pgc.16 - gsmtp
Connection closed by foreign host.
#
```

So please help me to identify why this is happening.
This issue started to appear after a firewall upgrade in linux.
It was working fine in linux earlier.

EDIT:

Posted the question on serverfault.com since it may come under that forum.

https://serverfault.com/questions/834958/sending-mail-via-java-is-working-in-eclipse-but-not-in-linux-server

Please answer it there if this question is closed. Thank you

Comment: *"This issue started to appear after a firewall upgrade in linux."* - Then this is NOT a programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the http://serverfault.com/  ServerFault is the best place for system administration and networking questions ... which is what this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I got to wait 40 minutes to post in serverfault.com Any way to migrate this question to that forum?

Comment: Sadly, no.  Or at least, I can't.  Maybe you could flag it for moderator attention, and ask them if they can migrate it.